# no data from the kinect

Tags: openni, openni-kinect, ubuntu, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI everyone.Im using openni kinect to get the data image from the Kinect,I followed the steps online ,on ros.org   but i dont get any data from the kinect.
thanks in advance for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11777/no-data-from-the-kinect/) by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-02**:
You need to post a lot more information to get useful help.  Se the guidelines for asking questions http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support linked from the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@bassim you have already asked this question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/2641/kinect-rospackage

If the answers are not helping you post a comment below the answer and tell them what happened when you followed the instructions in the answer, or update your original question. Please do not open yet another question asking the same thing over and over.

please follow the guidelines at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0